# Order success page as a tab in Magento 2 one page checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

Can we set checkout page like below mentioned format in magento 2.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to world of knockoutJS !!!

Comment: @Vivek I am not gud in knockoutJs.. Can you please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can refer this URL's. May be that can help you bit.
https://inchoo.net/magento-2/dont-mess-magento-2-checkout/
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_overview.html